# How load multiple images from the url to a viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

i am new in android. I need to load **multiple images** from the `URL` to a `viewpager`  by using `lazyloading`

images are not from the drawable

**These are my urls**:

```
String[] imagUrl={
    "http://img6a.flixcart.com/image/shoe/b/v/g/black-coaster-globalite-10-200x200-imadw577jjh5fsry.jpeg",
    "http://img6a.flixcart.com/image/shoe/b/v/g/black-coaster-globalite-10-200x200-imadw577shaeghnn.jpeg",

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, there is a good Library Called:(`picasso`) you can use it.

Here is the tutorial:

http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-use-picasso-library-in-android

And for codes:

```
//Initialize ImageView
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

//Loading image from below url into imageView

Picasso.with(this)
   .load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE")
   .into(imageView);

Picasso.with(this)
       .load("Your second image url")
       .into(imageView2);
```

With the best results, you can this.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i need to load multiple images into a viewpager

Comment: Yes, I need a viewpager mainly

Comment: i have a list of url's. i need to load these urls in a single  imageview using viewpager